# Cloud endpoints v1 to v2 migration causes 404 after promotion

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've migrated my java appengine project to Endpoints 2.0, I successfully tested it locally in dev environment so I deployed new version to appengine. I've tested newly deployed version with APis explorer (via -dot-.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer) and with my Android client after changing root url (via setRootUrl), so far so good, everything works as expected I see valid calls to endpoints in GAE logs (using new _ah/api/ urls). So I've promoted this version to default so it will receive all traffic and this totally failed - each calls ends with 404 and in logs I see request via old _ah/spi urls). 
It's even mentioned in migration doc:

> If requests are shown with having paths beginning with /_ah/api, then
>   Endpoints Frameworks 2.0 is now serving your API. 
>   The logs should not
>   show any requests with paths beginning with /_ah/spi. These requests
>   indicate that the Cloud Endpoints 1.0 proxy is still serving requests.

but I have no idea how to change it.

Comment: There's an ongoing bug with a fix that should release soon. Revert to the old version for now.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I was staring to pulling may hairs out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an ongoing bug with a fix that should release soon, you can revert to the old version for now.
For reference here's [**the link to bug in issue tracker**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76031966)

Comment: For reference here's link to bug in issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76031966